# jQuery (or maybe the browser) is cache-breaking ajax loaded scripts

Tags: asp.net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, caching

I'm loading a view page via an `$.ajax()` call with jQuery.  I'm explicitly setting the "cache" option to true.  Nowhere in the application are we using `$.ajaxSetup()` to specify otherwise.

Here's the ajax request setup:

```
$(".viewDialogLink").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr("href"),
        dataType: "html",
        type: "GET",
        cache: true,
        success: function(data) { $("#dlgViews").html(data).dialog("open"); }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The response comes back successfully.  The dialog opens, and some content displays.

***HOWEVER***

There are script tags in the returned html.  For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://../jsapi/arcgis/?v=1.4"></script>
```

Now - in the response text, these look normal.  But the actual browser requests for these scripts, as seen from FireBug, *include a cache-breaker parameter in the query string*. They look like:

`http://serverapi.arcgisonline.com/jsapi/arcgis/?v=1.4&_=1264703589546`.

None of the other resources in the loaded html - css or images - include the cache breaker in their request.

What is going on?  How do I turn this cache breaker off?

Comment: We're using jquery 1.3.2 by the way.

Comment: Is this happening in all browsers or only FF? You can use Firebug lite to test in different browsers.

Comment: The loading is definitely blocked at the same place in IE, although I haven't checked the request specifically.  I'll go check it out.

Comment: Yep, it's happening in IE as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate your issue on my test server.  I then changed from jquery 1.3.2 to 1.4.1.  With Jquery 1.4.1 it doesn't add the cache-breaking string.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Of course, using 1.4.1 might not be an option for you.

Comment: Crap.  We're stuck with 1.3.2 for now, but we're early in the dev cycle - perhaps jQuery UI will be compatible with 1.4 soon and we can upgrade.  Thanks for testing this out, much appreciated!