# Can jQuery check against the browser's cache before dynamically inserting a script element?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching

I have some HTML being pulled from the server via AJAX, which includes `<script>` tags. When appending this new html into the document I have found that -- regardless of whether the script already exists in the cache -- my browser is hitting the server again with a GET request to track down the `.js` file.

In some instances this creates quite a gap of time between when the HTML has returned from the initial AJAX call and when the content is fully rendered and scripts executed.

It's interesting that $(document).append(scripts) seems to bypass the browser's normal caching mechanisms. Does anyone know of a good way to force jQuery to check against the cache when adding script elements?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156973/jquery-or-maybe-the-browser-is-cache-breaking-ajax-loaded-scripts?rq=1

Comment: I don't know why `.append` would do that, but `ajax` has a `cache` option. Since `getScript` boils down to `ajax`, that may work.

Comment: @Greg We're using 1.6.4, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @pimvdb I tried a workaround like that initially, having it do a `$.ajax()` for each script with `cache : true`. This would speed things up when the HTML I wanted to add contained duplicate `<script>` elements, but it would still always try to fetch the first instance of it, regardless of the fact that the browser should have it cached already from earlier browsing.

Comment: @Greg again. Looking closer at the GET requests in Firebug, yes, that is exactly what it is doing. jQuery must have reverted to appending that cache-breaking string to the end of .js urls again some time after ~v1.4, because we are definitely using a newer version.